# how to add the content of the cell of table view in other view when clicked on cell in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to add the content of the cell of tableview in other view when i click on the tableview cell , how can i pass the values of the cell to other view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want use the text of a cellview for example you can do that in your UITableViewDelegate (or your UITableViewController):

```
// Tells the delegate that the specified row is now deselected.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     UITableViewCell *targetCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     NSString *contentCell = [targetCell textLabel];

     // Do something with the contentCell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your table view delegate (by default, it's the table view controller) implement the following method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Use indexPath as you did in -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: to get the values you need. To avoid unexpected behavior you should extract the values from your model rather than the cell.